# Removing msql-libs using yum removes many critical applications

Tags: mysql, centos, yum

I'm trying to delete msyql 5.1 and install mysql 5.7 on Centos 6.9 However when I enter

```
"yum remove mysql-libs-5.1.73-8.el6_8.x86_64"
```

it shows a whole slew of applications such as crontab, chrome, redhat-lsb-core, postfix and many others that will be deleted because they have a dependency on it.

From googling, I saw there is a "swap" option, but can I do this for each application? Do both the old and the new MySql libraries have to be installed?

Another option is to leave the old dependency there, and install the new one. But it seems like this could throw off the mysql install...it might somehow find the old dependency - or the existing apps might find the new dependency.

A third option is to re-install all the deleted applications, but figuring out how to install mysql was tricky enough. How do I know which ones are critical or not, for one thing? I definitely need crontab and chrome. The other "redhat-lsb" onese look important. Also postfix.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: Have you read this? https://www.stephenrlang.com/2018/01/mysql-5-1-to-mysql-5-7-upgrade-on-centos/  --  It's a pretty drawn out process ...  If you were in a virtual environment, it might be worth spinning up a separate server .. Building MySQL 5.7 and then swapping the data.

Comment: Yes, I gave it shot, but it didn't work, not sure why. I think it's a non-standard mysql distro, though, and I'd rather stick with the main one.

Comment: @JackBeNimble Are you trying to do an in-place upgrade of `mysql` with data or just the `libs`? What version of `mysql` do you have installed and working now? - This may also be better suited to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) rather then here as well since its a question about upgrading rather than programming...

Comment: I'm deleting the old version and installing the new version, so no data involved. I think the yum install took care of it when I went with option 2, which was to leave the old dependency there. Yum upgraded it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid issues such as this, CentOS/Redhat has provided another way to get latest packages of MySQL, PHP, Python etc.. through Software Collections(SCL).
Using SCL you can have multiple versions of MySQL running on the same server without any conflict or dealing with dependency.
https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL
https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-mysql57/

Comment: One if the issues I had with the initial install of mysql  5.7 was that it defaulted to el7 (instead of el6), which is incompatible with Centos 6.9. By installing a specific rpm (http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el6-7.noarch.rpm), I was able to update /etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community-source.repo to specify the correct version of mysql. Will this be handled by the SCL?

Comment: MySQL versions in CentOS 6 SCL are only for CentOS 6, as RPMs in SCL are released by Redhat itself you can rely on its stability. I have been using it for a while without changing any repo file.

Comment: I ended up just leaving that one dependency in there and deleting the rest. When I did the yum install, it miraculously upgraded the old dependency to the new one, and left the apps it was going to delete in place and updated for the new dependency. But it's good to know about the SCL anyway.